# Spring cache repository find one entity by id

Tags: java, spring, caching, spring-cache

I have a data repository DAO class that gets data from DB and it has following methods that my controller/service class calls:

```
@Override
public Account getOne(final String id) {
 this.namedParameterJdbcTemplate.queryForObject(this.BY_ID,
            namedParameters,
            new Mapper());
}

@Cacheable(value = "accounts")
@Override
public List<Account> getAll() {
    return this.namedParameterJdbcTemplate.query(this.ALL, new Mapper());
}

@CacheEvict(value = "accounts", allEntries = true)
public void evictAll() {

}
```

I am caching the result of an expensive `getAll()`  call. 
This is refreshed also by a scheduler calling evictAll().

My question is how can I cache `getOne()` as it takes a id param. 
Should I create a new cache or can use existing one "accounts" with reference to the `id`. Any ideas with some samples or pointers to examples will be much appreciated.

Comment: Presumably they'll have entirely different cache keys because of the different number of parameters; I am fairly sure you'll get an error on startup if Spring can't figure out how to keep them separate.

Comment: Assuming that you cache ```getOne``` What happens when the Db is updated for a given key? The cache should be updated with the values matching that given key. So the cache update strategy should be in this regard depending on the key.

Comment: @alainlompo this is exactly what I need and will be useful to see an example :)